# Getting an "undeclared identifier" error? why?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors

I am getting the following errors:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
error C2065: 'month' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'day' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'year' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'month' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'day' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'year' : undeclared identifier
```

I am running Visual Studio.

And here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
    char middle;
    char first[30], last[30];
    printf("WHat us ur midint?");
    printf("\n");
    scanf(" %c", &middle);
    printf("\n");
    printf("WHat us ur name?");
    printf("\n");
    scanf(" %s %s", first, last);
    printf("ur name is %s %c %s\n\n", first, middle, last);
    printf("\n");
    int month, day, year;
    scanf(" %d/%d/%d", &month, &day, &year);
    printf("Birthdate: %d/%d/%d\n\n", month, day, year);
}
```

Does anyone know why these errors are happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 does not support c99 and c99 mixed declarations and statements.
You have to put all your declarations (`month`, `day`, `year`) at the top of the `main`  function.

Answer (score 2):

When compiling a C program, MSVC doesn't allow declarations to follow statements in a block (it uses old C90 rules - support for declarations mixed with statements was added to C in the 1999 standard).

Move the declaration of `int month, day, year;` to the top of your program:

```
char middle;
char first[30], last[30];
int month, day, year;

...
```

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Feel free to give one of these answers the check mark.  Looks like @ouah answered 10 seconds before I did :)

Comment: Sorry but I had to move the check mark from your question to ouah's, since he answered first, he deserves it. Hope you understand adn thank you.